# Predicting chunks with M models in R

Tags: r, loops, predict, rpart

I have dataset (`HEART`). I split it into chunks. I would like to predict each chunk with his (`M=3`) previous models. In this case, I would like to predict chunk number 10 - with models 7,8,9. chunk 9 - with models 6,7,8... chunk 4 - with models 1,2,3.
Here is my code:

```
library(caret)
dat1 <- read.csv(url("http://archive.ics.uci.edu/ml/machine-learning-databases/heart-disease/processed.cleveland.data"), header = FALSE,sep = ",")
colnames(dat1) <- c(LETTERS[1:(ncol (dat1)-1)],"CLA")
dat1$CLA<-as.factor (dat1$CLA)

chunk <- 30
n <- nrow(dat1)
r  <- rep(1:floor(n/chunk),each=chunk)[1:n]
d <- split(dat1,r)

N<-floor(n/chunk)
cart.models <- list()
for(i in 1:N){cart.models[[i]]<-rpart(CLA~ ., data = d[[i]]) }
for (i in (1+M):N) { k=0
  for (j in (i-M):(i-1)) { 
    k=k+1
    d[[i]][,(ncol(d[[i]])+k)]<-(predict(cart.models[[j]], d[[i]][,c(-14)], type = "class") )
    } 
     }
```

I get the following Error:

```
Error in `[<-.data.frame`(`*tmp*`, , (ncol(d[[i]]) + k), value = c(1L,  : 
  new columns would leave holes after existing columns
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your question is a bit puzzling, you load `caret` without using any functions from it. The objective seems like a time series analyses but instead of building on one chunk and predicting on the one that comes after it, you have a more complex desire, so `createTimeSlices` from `caret` won't do the trick. 
You could create custom folds in caret with `index` and `indexOut` arguments in `trainControl` but that would ultimately lead to the creation of more models (21 to be exact) than is required for the presented objective (9). So I do believe loops are an appropriate way:

create the models:

```
library(rpart)

N <- 9
cart.models <- list()
for(i in 1:N){
  cart.models[[i]] <- rpart(CLA~ ., data = d[[i]])
}
```

`N` can be `9` since `10` will not be utilized later on.

create a matrix to store the values:

```
cart.predictions <- matrix(nrow = chunk, ncol = length(4:10)*3)
```

it should have the same number of rows as there are predictions in each chunk (so 30) and it should have as many columns are there are predictions (three models for 4:10 chunks).

```
k <- 0 #as a counter
for (j in 4:10) { #prediction on chunks 4:10
  p <- j-3  
  pred <- list()
  for(i in p : (p+2)) { #using models (chink - 3) : (chunk - 1)
    k = k + 1 
    predi <- predict(cart.models[[i]], d[[j]], type = "class")
    cart.predictions[,k] <- predi
  }
}
```

this creates a numeric matrix for predictions. By default when R converts factors to numeric  it gives them numbers: 1 to the first level, 2 to the second etc - so to get the levels (0:4) you can just:

```
cart.predictions <- as.data.frame(cart.predictions - 1)
```

to create the column names:

```
names <- expand.grid(3:1, 4:10)
names$Var1 <- with(names, Var2 - Var1) 

colnames(cart.predictions) <- make.names(paste0(names$Var1,"_", names$Var2))
```

lets check if it correct:

prediction from model `5` on chunk `6` converted to numeric

```
as.numeric(as.character(predict(cart.models[[5]], d[[6]], type = "class")))
```

should be equal to

```
cart.predictions[["X5_6"]] #that's how the names were designed

all.equal(as.numeric(as.character(predict(cart.models[[5]], d[[6]], type = "class"))),
          cart.predictions[["X5_6"]])
#output
TRUE
```

or you can create a character matrix in the first place:

```
cart.predictions <- matrix(data = NA_character_, nrow = chunk, ncol = length(4:10)*3)

k <- 0 #as a counter
for (j in 4:10) { 
  p <- j-3
  pred <- list()
  for(i in p : (p+2)) {
    k = k + 1 
    predi <- predict(cart.models[[i]], d[[j]], type = "class")
    cart.predictions[,k] <- predi
  }
} 

cart.predictions <- as.data.frame(cart.predictions)
```

This should be the preferred method if the classes are certain "names".